# Prevent EF 4.1 from deleting my database diagram

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, database-diagram

Is there a way to prevent Entity Framework Code-First from deleting my database diagrams when it is re-building my database?

Comment: Did you map the system tables?

Comment: Not yet =)  Are you saying that doing a code-first mapping of sysdiagrams is the only way?

Comment: No, there's always the DB generation power pack. Or put your diagrams in a different DB?

Comment: Well, I guess I'd prefer to keep my diagrams in my database.  Can you point out an article or provide some basic instructions on how the power pack can help with this?

Comment: The power pack lets you not drop and recreate the DB when changing metadata. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` to create your database you can use SQL Migrations
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx. It won't drop the database and will generate alter commands (Incremental database development) . So you can keep your diagram and existing data.